# AWS AMI: Need to explicitly remove apt locks when provisioning AMI from bionic

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, apt, packer, amazon-ebs

I am trying to provision via `packer` and its `ansible` provisioner a custom AMI, based off the official `Ubuntu 18.04` ami as provided by AWS.

My packer provisioning that searches for the appropriate base ami is as follows:

```
  "source_ami_filter": {
    "filters": {
      "virtualization-type": "hvm",
      "name": "*{{user `ami-os`}}*",
      "root-device-type": "ebs",
      "architecture": "x86_64"
    },
    "owners": ["amazon"],
    "most_recent": true
  },
```

where I pass on the fly the variable:

```
-var "ami-os=ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server"
```

Since the ami does not have `python2` installed and I want to provision using `ansible`, I have to perform via `raw`:

```
- name: pre_tasks --> Install python2 for Ansible
  raw: bash -c "test -e /usr/bin/python || (apt -qqy update && apt install -qqy python-minimal)"
  become: yes
  register: output
  changed_when: output.stdout != ""
  when: ansible_isbionic
```

However, in most cases the above fails with the message that the process `apt` is locked:

```
amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 100, "stderr": "\nWARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.\n\n\nWARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.\n\nE: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)\nE: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?\nShared connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.\r\n", "stderr_lines": ["", "WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.", "", "", "WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.", "", "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)", "E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?", "Shared connection to 127.0.0.1 closed."], "stdout": "190 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.\n", "stdout_lines": ["190 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them."]}
```

To overcome this, I am explicitly performing:

```
- name: pre_tasks.yml --> Kill any apt commnds running
  raw: bash -c "killall apt apt-get || echo 'no apt-related processes found'"
  become: yes
  when: ansible_isbionic


- name: pre_tasks.yml --> Remove apt lock files
  raw: bash -c "rm -f /var/lib/apt/lists/lock"
  become: yes
  when: ansible_isbionic


- name: pre_tasks.yml --> Remove apt cache lock files
  raw: bash -c "rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/lock"
  become: yes
  when: ansible_isbionic


- name: pre_tasks.yml --> Remove apt cache lock files
  raw: bash -c "rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock"
  become: yes
  when: ansible_isbionic
```

Any idea why the `apt` process gets locked?

Comment: Do you have lsof installed in the AMI? If so can you add a task to `lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock` or `lsof +D /var/lib/dpkg`. Hopefully would give you some insight into what is locking apt, and therefore a clean way to resolve the condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can advice you to wait for boot/update to complete but not kill lock-file.

We use this tricks in our cloud provisioning scripts:

```
while [ ! -f /var/lib/cloud/instance/boot-finished ]; do
  # wait...
done

while fuser /var/lib/apt/lists/lock >/dev/null 2>&1 ; do
  # wait...
done
```

When using Ansible you can pack this instructions into bash script and use `script` module instead of many `raw` executions. `script` module also doesn't need Python to be present on the managed host.

Comment: very helpful feedback; will give it a try and post results;

Answer (score 1):

I think this perhaps a more modern answer, although Im not sure it is any more correct

```
cloud-init status -w
```